# Split string by spaces, but not spaces within newlines, and preserve newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"word1 word2 \ngroup of words\n"
```

I need to split it by spaces except for the spaces that occur between 2 `\n`, and preserve the `\n` character. So the result would be an array like this:

```
[
 "word1",
 "word2",
 "\ngroup of words\n"
]
```

I've found results that achieve the same thing with `,` instead of `\n`, but it's not possible for me to replace it with any other character.

I'm currently using the code below, but it doesn't preserve the `\n`.

```
input.split('\n').flatMap((s,i)=>i%2?`\n${s.trim()}\n`:s.trim().split(' ')).filter(v=>v)
```

Notes:

If the input string has words before `\n`, there will always be a space before it, i.e. a string can contain `word1 \ngroup 1\n`, but never `word1\ngroup 1\n`

A string can also contain multiple groups, like `word1 \ngroup 1\n word2 \ngroup 2\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = "word1 word2 \ngroup of words\n";
console.log(text.match(/\n.*\n|\S+/g))
```

The `/\n.*\n|\S+/g` pattern matches multiple occurrences of

- `\n.*\n` - a line feed char, then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars (as many as possible) and then a line feed
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CAqtn/1).